# How to sort and ignore spaces?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting

I'm trying to sort a file but I can't get the results I want.
I have this file :

```
742550111       aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa     2008    3       1       1
5816470687      aa a dissertation for the       933     2       2       2
```

Each field is separated by a tabulation, and I would like to sort on the second column.

When I try `sort test.txt -t\t -k 2`, the output is the same as in the file.
But the output I want to have is :

```
5816470687      aa a dissertation for the       933     2       2       2
742550111       aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa     2008    3       1       1
```

I think that's because *sort* ignores the spaces between the words.

So I tried with this command : `LC_ALL=C sort test.txt -t\t -k 2`, but it still doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash replaces `$'\t'` with a real tab:

```
LC_ALL=C sort file -t $'\t' -k 2
```

Output:

```
5816470687      aa a dissertation for the       933     2       2       2
742550111       aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa     2008    3       1       1
```

Comment: The man page for `sort` shows `file` as the last argument under SYNOPSIS, so why place it where you have, should it not be the last argument of the command?

Comment: I'm assuming he/she used GNU sort. GNU sort can handle it.

Comment: Yes I put the `file` as the last argument, that was just for a test.
I actually run this command
`for X in tri/small*; do LC_ALL=C sort -t $'\t' -k 2 < $X > $X-sorted; done`

Comment: Yes, I know it can handle it; however, isn't it better to show proper form? That was more a rhetorical question. IMO following the man page, `sort [option]… [file]…`, just makes more sense to me. Anyway, +1 for "Bash replaces `$'\t'` with a real tab:" as I found that helpful.

Comment: @user3439894: Yes, I've taken over everything and only corrected what was necessary. When I create the command, I place the filename at the end.